# Objectbox distinct() query

Tags: android, database, database-design, objectbox

I have two entities. 1) `Tablets` 2) `Mobiles`. Both have few hundred entries. Both have property `Company`.

I have a search bar to search companies. When user search for company,
how to extract recently added 10 companies (should be distinct) from both entities?

I can do manually, something like below...

1. List `companies` = find all companies in `Tablets` + find all companies in `Mobiles`
2. List `distinctCompanied` = find distinct values from `companies` & sort them descending by record creation date
3. List `requiredResult` = find first 10 entries

But it will be very slow when the database grows to several thousand entries.
I read http://objectbox.io/documentation/queries, but i don't get how to do it with in-built functions. Any ideas?

Comment: First question: why do you have separate classes for tablets and mobiles? I would guess they share most properties. You could have a new property for the type to differentiate.

Comment: What if have no choice?